# Where do I store Layer level information in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, metadata

I am using a python script to load the content of some files to layers in QGIS. These file usually contain header information that I am skipping (like the `Number of header lines to discard` parameter in the `Delimited Text` dialog box).
I would like however to preserve this information as I may have to output my data in the original format.
Where can I store these header ? Is `Metadata` the way to go ? If so, how do I store my information there and retrieve it later ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use layer custom properties. These are set through calling `setCustomProperty` on the layer, and retrieved via `customProperty`. They are saved and restored along with the current project.

Comment: Perfect! I was under the impression `Metadata` wasn't really the correct way to go but I coundn't locate this `setCustomProperty`. Thanks